# Can't connect php to SQL server, error:0

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, mysql

I've set up an internal Ubuntu 14.04 LAMP server.  I can access SQL when using Putty, but when I try to connect via php script all my pages were blank... Then I tried to debug it by simply connecting  to the IP address and I get a (111) error with no port and an error: 0 after 3 minutes of attempted connection when I say the port is 80.

Any ideas would be awesome.  Thanks!

Comment: Most likely the SQL server (mariadb?) is not at port 80. At port 80 you probably have the web server (aparche?). Try to search log files or post a snippet from your php code trying to connect to the SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:

If you have lines like this :

```
skip-networking
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

In your my.cnf configuration file, you should comment them (add a # at the beginning of the lines), and restart MySQL.

Of course, to do this, you must be the administrator of the server.

Solution 2:

If you could login as root to mysql then you create a new user:

```
CREATE USER 'root'@'your_ip' IDENTIFIED BY  'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO  'root'@'your_ip' IDENTIFIED BY  'password';
```

If you don't want to create then simply give grant permission to your root user with % like following.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO  'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY  'password';
```